# ios opencv2.framework is quite strange

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I am new to Xcode for ios. I encountered a very strange issue.

My Xcode is 7 under MacOS EI. and I download the opencv samples for ios
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_for_ios_book_samples

And after that I download the opencv2.framework for ios not Mac (they are different)

but, after I unzipped the opencv2.framework, the folders' names are very strange. There is no folder named "opencv2" but "Headers". If so, how could you find the correct path????

In addition, where is the shared library? the next folder is named "opencv2" without any suffix.

In order to make the paths correct, I changed the "h" files folder name to be "opencv2", so the project can find the header files. But still can not link to the library. The error is as follows.

ld: framework not found opencv2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Although I have set the search path for headers and library.

I have searched a lot but no answers, Could you please give some ideas??

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it!!

1. first in the "Headers" folder, create a folder named "opencv2" and then cut all the other files into it. This solves that "cannot find the include file".
2. just drop this modified opencv2.framework into the Xcode project's frameworks. Then appears a window. Remember to choose "copy file if needed".
3. change to the TARGET build Settings, just add the search headers path.

Done!